# Creating aws aurora with 'require_secure_transport'

Tags: terraform, amazon-aurora

According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Security.html) doc :

```
You can require that all user connections to your Aurora MySQL DB cluster use SSL/TLS by using the require_secure_transport DB cluster parameter.
```

Been looking through terraform docs and samples. Not seeing if this setting is available.

Does terraform have a method to set arbitrary values if they aren't supported as module params?

Comment: Hi ... sorry didn't get your requirement..could you please elaborate it? Is it like how to enable 'require_secure_transport' flag in terraform for AWS aurora?

Comment: Client requirement that end to end communications be encrypted. It would be great if we could use ACM certs here.

Answer (score 1):

@ethrbunny If my guess is not wrong, you are trying to set SSL/TLS connection for mysql DB cluster in aws aurora using terraform? I guess for this first you need to create custom DB cluster parameter group in aws aurora and specify that group name in your terraform module.

Reference :

[Terraform Registery](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/rds-aurora/aws/latest) Look for 'db_cluster_parameter_group_name' tag

[Terraform aws aurora github link](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds-aurora/blob/master/main.tf)

As per AWS document we can set this parameter in a custom DB cluster parameter group. The parameter isn't available in DB instance parameter groups.

Reference : [aws aurora documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Security.html) refer 'Notes' section

```
The require_secure_transport parameter is only available for Aurora MySQL version 5.7. You can set this parameter in a custom DB cluster parameter group. The parameter isn't available in DB instance parameter groups.
```